# Nodejs express code not ending without closing db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, monk

I have written a nodejs code in which I have used Mongo DB. 
I am inserting data in loop and when everything gets inserted the code does not exit and when i close the db forcefully using `db.close()` my code does not write full data in database.

Can somebody please provide some help?

Comment: Look at examples on google. If you don't find what you need then the shortest possible code example to illustrate the problem would help.

Comment: May be db.close - disconnect with the db server without successful inserts. uses 'async' library on successful response from server. use db.close

Comment: i checked a lot of examples on google.                                               for(var id in map2){
//   // users.insert(map2[doc]);
//   
//
//    )
//    console.log(true);
//    //console.log
   console.log(map2.length);
}

users.insert(map2.[doc],function(err,res)
{db.close();})}

});    please ignore the syntax.map2 is the array where all my elements are users is my collection and if i dont do db.close then it works successfully without ending the code but when i do it ends without successfully writing the data.i used all methods to insert even using queue implementation

Comment: Please use the [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34260385/edit) link on your question to add information rather than supply in comments. But your basic problem is a `for` loop with an async operation inside does not respect the completion of that operation. You need to wait for completion of each async insert before iterating the next loop. Spend some time reading the node [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module documentation for various flow control methods.

Comment: i think your coding issue. Put an example of your code or code itself

Comment: Please put your code. The information provided is very insufficient.